# SWIG: How to pass a vector of complex numbers from C++ to python

Tags: python, c++, vector, swig

I need to pass a list of complex numbers from python to C++ to initialize a vector and after some operations, I need to pass the vector of complex double back to python.

Here is my try:

## example.i

```
%module example

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
%include <complex.i>
%include <std_complex.i>
namespace std {
    %template(DoubleVector)  vector<double>;
    %template(ComplexVector) vector<std::complex<double> >;
}
%include "example.h"
```

## example.cpp

```
#include "example.h"


void my_class::set_value(Complex a, std::vector<Complex> v)
{
    com1 = {1,2};
    comV = v;
}

void my_class::print_value()
{
    std::cout << com1<< std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<comV.size(); i++)
        std::cout<<comV[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

## example.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>
#include <complex>

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;

class my_class 
{
    private:    
        Complex com1;
        std::vector<Complex> comV;
    public:
        my_class(){ }
        void set_value(Complex a, std::vector<Complex> v);
        void print_value();
};
```

I compiled and give me the following error when I try to test it:

```
import example
c = example.my_class()
c.set_value(complex(1.0,3.5), [complex(1,1.2), complex(2.0,4.2)])
c.print_value()

return _example.my_class_set_value(self, a, v)
TypeError: in method 'my_class_set_value', argument 3 of type 'std::vector< Complex,std::allocator< Complex > >'
```

I don't know Where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put an explicit instantiation of `ComplexVector` in the SWIG-file, otherwise it won't work.  Your mistake was that you did not qualify `std::complex<double>` properly (you forgot the namespace).

```
%module example

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_complex.i"
namespace std {
    %template(DoubleVector)  vector<double>;
    %template(ComplexVector) vector<std::complex<double>>;
}
%include "example.h"
```

Futhermore `my_class::print_value()` is missing a return statement which will lead to an illegal instruction.